# display the CMD console in a window in GUI - PySimpleGUI

Tags: python-3.x, pysimplegui

I'm creating a GUI using PySimpleGUI and want to have a frame that displays the output prints of all the functions in the program (as in the cmd console).
I tried using (relevant code lines):

```
def hello():
    print('hello')

layout = [[sg.Frame("Output console", [[sg.Text(" ", size=(0, 1), key='-OUTPUT-')]])]]
window['-OUTPUT-'].update(hello())
```

I can see the print in the console but not in the Frame in the GUI.
How can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show the output like in CMD console, you should use the `sg.Multiline`, not the `sg.Text` which is just a label.

To redirect the output of stdout and stderr, set options `reroute_stdout=True` and `reroute_stderr=True`, also set option `autoscroll=True` to automatically scroll as more data added to the end of element.

Demo Code - GUI will update only back to `window.read`

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def hello():
    print('hello')

frame_layout = [[sg.Multiline("", size=(80, 20), autoscroll=True,
    reroute_stdout=True, reroute_stderr=True, key='-OUTPUT-')]]

layout = [
    [sg.Frame("Output console", frame_layout)],
    [sg.Push(), sg.Button("Say Hello")],
]
window = sg.Window("Title", layout, finalize=True)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == "Say Hello":
        hello()

window.close()
```

To update GUI in realtime, you can call `update(value, append=True)` and `window.refresh`, not to use the `print` statement, or

Following code show the way to print to `sg.multiline` immediately. To avoid   stop GUI working for long printing, mutlithread required here. It will not work for real time printing during event loop because loop is working on your printing statement, then back to window.read after it done.

It is much complex, not sure if any bug.

```py
import sys
from time import sleep
from datetime import datetime
import threading
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def print_task():
    global printing
    while printing:
        print(datetime.now().strftime("%H-%M-%S"), datetime.now().strftime("%H-%M-%S"))
        sleep(0.5)

class Unbuffered(object):
    def __init__(self, window):
        self.window = window
    def write(self, data):
        self.window.write_event_value("OUT", data)
    def writelines(self, datas):
        self.window.write_event_value("OUT", ''.join(datas))

frame_layout = [[sg.Multiline("", size=(80, 20), autoscroll=True, key='-OUTPUT-')]]

layout = [
    [sg.Frame("Output console", frame_layout)],
    [sg.Push(), sg.Button("Print"), sg.Button('Stop')],
]
window = sg.Window("Title", layout, finalize=True)
old_stdout, old_stderr = sys.stdout, sys.stderr
sys.stdout = Unbuffered(window)
sys.stderr = Unbuffered(window)
printing = False

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == 'Print':
        if not printing:
            printing = True
            threading.Thread(target=print_task, daemon=True).start()
    elif event == 'Stop':
            printing = False
    elif event == "OUT":
        window['-OUTPUT-'].update(values["OUT"], append=True)

printing = False
sys.stdout, sys.stderr = old_stdout, old_stderr
window.close()
```

Comment: Thanks @Jason Yang.
it displays the prints but at the end of the run and not in real time.
Is it possible to see them in real time?

Comment: GUI updated only when loop back to `window.read()`, let me think about how to update character by character ...

Comment: Updated as above.